# Rails: Single table inheritance and find(:all) in parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand how STI works, in that I have say a Post model that
contains posts on a forum and several sub-posts like
'ordinaryUserPost' and 'adminUserPost' etc.

Now, I want to define the same method in each of the sub-posts, but
the method would do something different in each case, eg

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AdminUserPost < Post
  def background_color
    'rockstar red'
  end
end

class OrdinaryUserPost < Post
  def background_color
    'pale blue'
  end
end
```

(yes its a silly example).  Now in my thread controller I do Post.find
(:all) and it gives me a list of posts I need to render, but they are
'Post' objects, not AdminUserPost or OrdinaryUserPost - so I cannot
just get my background_color method!  I would have to do a find on
each type of user post separately ...

Is there anyway I can do:

```
Post.find(:all)
```

And in the resultant array get a list of AdminUserPost and
OrdinaryUserPost objects instead of Post objects?

Or is there a nice way of 'casting' my Post objects into AdminUserPost's and OrdinaryUserPost's as appropriate?

EDIT:

This works as expected - provided you have a column called 'type' in the Post class.  If your column is called something else, such as 'post_type' then you need to add:

```
self.inheritance_column = 'post_type'
```

In ALL the child models (AdminUserPost and OrdinaryUserPost in this example) and in the parent (Post).

Thanks,

Stephen.

Comment: Do you have any field in the db to differentiate which posts are of which type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double check that the posts table has a column 'type' (string). If the AdminUserPosts and OrdinaryUserPosts are written to the table 'posts' and the type column is correct, you should get the subclass behavior you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected - provided you have a column called 'type' in the Post class.  If your column is called something else, such as 'post_type' then you need to add:

```
self.inheritance_column = 'post_type'
```

In ALL the child models (AdminUserPost and OrdinaryUserPost in this example) and in the parent (Post).

Answer (score -2):

Post.find(:all) will give you Post, becouse you are serching in Post, not in AdminUserPost. If you want AdminUserPost use:

```
AdminUserPost.find(:all)
```

but I guess it will find the same posts as Post.find(:all) will find.

I think named_scope will help you:

```
# in model
Class Post << ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :admin_posts, :conditions => {:owner == 'admin'}
  named_scope :ordinary_user_posts, :condition => {:owner != 'admin'}
end

# in controller
@posts = Post.admin_posts # returns admin posts

# or
@posts = AdminUserPost.admin_posts # returns admin posts in AdminUserPost class
```

I didn't try to use this inherited classes, but I think it will work.

You can learn more about named scopes here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I'm new in Rails community and I didn't hear about STI before. dbarker is right, I tried it and it works as you wanted.

Comment: Named scope isn't what I am looking for as that would result in two queries. I was hoping for a way to get all posts in one go, and for Rails to auto translate them into the correct child type!

Comment: If STI is set up correctly, Post.find(:all) will get all subclasses.